# In China, tar-ing a directory that keeps terminating. [Great Firewall issue ?]

Tags: ssh, migration, firewall

Background: Im located in China and using a VPN service routing my connection through the US. I'm using an SSH connection to a server in the US.

I'm trying to help transfer a server hosted on GoDaddy to Bluehost. The server Im using from GoDaddy has very poor service support and doesn't have rsync, scp, or git. I decided to tar up the directory of content that Im moving and do a wget pull on the new server.

Problem is that when I run the tar, I get a TERMINATED statement. I've attempted to run the tar a couple times now, but each time I get a TERMINATED statement. I should not its not always in the same place.

The last time I did this, I ran tar by viewing the contents of its process. I noticed that it TERMINATED when it passed over a statement "China-US Mid-air Plane Collision Incident" with a anchor tag to a site blocked in China.

Im wondering, even through I'm SSHing to a server in the US, is it possible for a tar to get disrupted because of the China firewall? Its am issue I dont understand very well. I wanted to ask incase anyone understood the reason for this issue.

(ps: If anyone has a better way to transfer files off of a hosting server, I am looking for alternatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know crappy shared hosting servers, I find it much more probable that some memory monitor kills your `tar` process because of memory consumption or something similar.

Comment: Yeah- Thats what I felt. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: wow. I hadn't tried SCP. Found a much better solution. thanks for your heads up!